# Some questions about what an inner product is, and what it means for a basis to be orthonormal.

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, inner-products

I have a vague understanding of the concepts mentioned in the title. But have some questions to clear things up:

Firstly, what does this mean on Wikipedia?

> For $\mathbb{R}^3$ the set of vectors $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is called the
> **standard basis** and forms and orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with *respect to the standard dot product*. Note that both the standard
> basis and standard dot product *rely on viewing* $\mathbb{R}^3$ *as the
> Cartesian product* $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

In italic are the things that I dont understand. What does it mean "in respect to the standard dot product", can you be an orthonormal basis with respect to a different inner product? If so, please give an example, and if that's not the case, what does this statement mean?

Also, what does it mean by "relies heavily on viewing $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the cartesian product"? How else could you possible view it?

Finally, what is a "cannonical inner product", It is mentioned on one of my linear algebra books, and is basically just the dot product, except it's not commutative since you take the complex conjugate of each component the first vector.

While also answering these questions, I'd like to know what an Inner-product actually is, and what is the motivation for developing them? Thank you

Comment: Orthonormality is always with respect to some inner product! There are plenty of examples of orthonormality WRT an inner product that's not the dot product. [Here's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). I think the "viewing $\Bbb R^3$ as the Cartesian product" thing is about viewing the three axes in $\Bbb R^3$ as somehow special. If you think of $\Bbb R^3$ as just three-dimensional space, then there's no canonical way to choose three axes. For example, $\{(a, b, c, d) \in \Bbb R^4 : a + b + c + d = 0\}$ is also three-dimensional - but there's no obvious canonical basis.

Comment: PS: learning maths from Wikipedia is not very highly advisable. Wikipedia is a great resource for reference and for broad overviews and interesting facts, but situations like yours will often occur! The best way to learn a subject that's new to you is to follow a book or some lectures or lectures notes that have been explicitly designed to build up the concepts in a motivated, coherent, sequential way.

Comment: Please focus on one question per post. Your two final questions *what an Inner-product actually is, and what is the motivation for developing them* should be posted separately from the previous ones, and have probably already been asked and answered on this site.

Answer (score 1):

*Every* basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb R$ is orthonormal with respect to a (unique) inner product $\langle~,~\rangle$ on $V$, defined by
$$\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i,\sum_{j=1}^ny_je_j
\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i.
$$
When $V$ has a canonical basis $\mathcal B$, the *canonical* inner product on $V$ is the one for which $\mathcal B$ is orthonormal.

As commented by @IzaakvanDongen, not every finite dimensional vector space over some field $K$ has a canonical basis, but $K^n$ does, and that basis is tied to the cartesian product structure of this vector space.

Finally, the definition of inner products on complex vector spaces differs from
the definition of inner products on real vector spaces, the only difference being that $\langle~,~\rangle$ is required to be antilinear w.r.t. its first argument, instead of linear (some authors choose the other convention: antilinearity w.r.t. the second argument).